# Prolog Recursion breakdown

Tags: recursion, prolog

Hi can someone breakdown this recursive code so i can fully understand the output it is giving. Im really confused as to how its working:

```
    listcomb([],[]).
    listcomb([X|Y], [X|Z]) :-
        listcomb(Y,Z).
    listcomb([_|Y],Z) :-
        listcomb(Y,Z).



    ?- listcomb([1,2,3], X).
    X = [1, 2, 3] ;
    X = [1, 2] ;
    X = [1, 3] ;
    X = [1] ;
    X = [2, 3] ;
    X = [2] ;
    X = [3] ;
    X = [].
```

thankyou

Comment: Have you tried doing a `trace` to see what happens?

Comment: trace just returns a bunch of chinese sumbols, think its broken ha

Comment: What Prolog interpreter are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It unifies the second argument with all possible combinations of elements from the first argument in the following way:

1. If the list is empty, you're done (first clause).
2. One possible combination is combine the head of the list with all possible combinations of the tail of the list (second clause)
3. Another possible combination is to discard the head of the list and just return all possible combinations of the tail of the list (third clause).

When run, the predicate will exhaust the second clause, than backtrace to the third clause, and so on, until exhausting all options and stopping with the first clause.